# Concatenate two column VBA. If Data update in last row automatically i need to get the concatenate value in the rows

Tags: excel, vba

Please find the below table I need to concatenate the "Suppler Name" & " Invoice NUM" in "Concatenate" column. The concatenate will if any changes made in cells it will reflect in concatenate column. (No need to click & start the macro)

```
 Supplier Name  Invoice NUM CONCATENATE
 Supplier Name  1   =CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2)
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1   
 Supplier Name  1
```

```
Sub Conctenate()

    Dim New1 As Worksheet
    Dim Gcol As Integer
    Dim Icol As Integer
    Dim RowNumA As Integer
    Dim RowNumB As Integer
    Dim RowNumC As Integer

    Set New1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Open")

    Gcol = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Icol = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    RowNumG = 2
    RowNumI = 2
    RowNumJ = 2

    For a = 1 To Gcol

        For b = 1 To Icol
            Sheets("Open").Range("J" & RowNumJ).Value = Range("G"&_
               RowNumG).Value & "-" & Range("I" & RowNumI).Value
            RowNumI = RowNumI + 1
            RowNumJ = RowNumJ + 1
        Next b

        RowNumI = 1
        RowNumG = RowNumG + 1

    Next a
End Sub
```

Final I got a perfect solution for concatenate please refer the below code.

```
   Sub Combine()

   Dim Cointer As Integer
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   Sheets("Open").Select

   For Counter = 2 To WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("G:G"))

    Range("J" & Counter) = Range("G" & Counter) & " " & Range("I" &_
     Counter)

   Next Counter

   End Sub
```

Comment: Convert your "table" to a proper table and the formula will automatically be applied to that column? No VBA needed

Comment: @brax I need to update the result when the data was updated. No need to runt the macro